# How to replace column values based on a list?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list like this:

```
x = ['Las Vegas', 'San Francisco, 'Dallas']
```

And a dataframe that looks a bit like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Las Vegas (Clark County), 25], ['New York', 23], 
        ['Dallas', 27]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['City', 'Value'])
```

I want to replace my city values in the DF  *"Las Vegas (Clark County)"* with *"Las Vegas"*. In my dataframe are multiple cities with different names which needs to be changed. I know I could do a regex expression to just strip off the part after the parentheses, but I was wondering if there was a more clever, generic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with `join`ed values of list by `|` for regex `OR` and then replace non matched values to original by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['City'] = df['City'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(x)})', expand=False).fillna(df['City'])
print (df)
        City  Value
0  Las Vegas     25
1   New York     23
2     Dallas     27
```

Another idea is use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with loop, but it should be slow if large Dataframe and many values in `list`:

```
for val in x:
    df.loc[df['City'].str.contains(val), 'City'] = val
```